# MPI - how to send avalue to a specific position in array

Tags: c++, mpi

I want so send a value to  a position in array of another process. 
so

```
1st process: MPI_ISend (&val..., process, ..)
2nd process: MPI_Recv (&array[i], ..., process, ...)
```

So I know the i number on the first process, I also know, that I can't use a variable - first send i and then val, as other processes can change i ( 2nd process is accepting messages from many others).

Answer (score 1):

First of all other send/receives should not/cannot  overwrite `i`. You should keep your messages clear and separated. That's what the `tag` is for! Also rank_2 can separate which rank did send the data. So you can have one `i` for every rank you await a message from.

Finally you might want to check out one-sided MPI communication (`MPI_Win`). With that technique rank_1 can 'drop' the message directly into rank_2's array at the position only known to rank_1.

Comment: I have a problem, that tags are used for other purposes and 1st process should send for example 4 values to 2nd process in cycle, so should another one, and another and so on. I cannot pack them, as they are not in consecutive locations. MPI_Put and Get are not really desirable. So,then only freeing tags and divide the information with them will help?

Comment: I'm not sure, but is sounds to me that `MPI_Gatherv` could solve your problems? You pack the messages in one array per rank (fill it in non-consecutive places, [or is this impossible?]) and then gather these local arrays in rank_2.